# Spark Find duplicate records for a field in RDD

Tags: apache-spark, duplicates, rdd

I have data set like
10,"Name",2016,"Country"
11,"Name1",2016,"country1"
10,"Name",2016,"Country"
10,"Name",2016,"Country"
12,"Name2",2017,"Country2"

My problem statement is I have to find total count and duplicates count by year . My Result should be (year, totalrecords, duplicates)
2016,4,3
2017,1,0.

I have tried to solve this problem by

```
val records = rdd.map {
              x => 
               val array = x.split(",")
               (array(2),x)
             }.groupByKey()
val duplicates = records.map {
                 x => val totalcount = x._2.size
                      val duplicates = // find duplicates in iterator
                     (x._1,totalcount,duplicates)
                }
```

It is running fine upto 10GB data. If I ran it on more data it is taking long time. I found that groupByKey is not a best approach.

Please suggest best approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite the sql expert to count the duplicates in the way your example shows. However I think this will get you started using dataframes. My understanding is that dataframes can perform significantly better than straight RDD.

```
scala> import com.databricks.spark.csv._
import com.databricks.spark.csv._

scala> 

scala> val  s = List("""10,"Name",2016,"Country"""", """11,"Name1",2016,"country1"""", """10,"Name",2016,"Country"""", """10,"Name",2016,"Country"""", """12,"Name2",2017,"Country2"""")
s: List[String] = List(10,"Name",2016,"Country", 11,"Name1",2016,"country1", 10,"Name",2016,"Country", 10,"Name",2016,"Country", 12,"Name2",2017,"Country2")

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(s)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[92] at parallelize at <console>:38

scala> 

scala> val df = new CsvParser().withDelimiter(',').withInferSchema(true).withParseMode("DROPMALFORMED").csvRdd(sqlContext, rdd)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C0: int, C1: string, C2: int, C3: string]

scala> 

scala> df.registerTempTable("test")

scala> 

scala> val dfCount = sqlContext.sql("select C2, count(*), count(distinct C0,C2,C1,C3) from test group by C2")
dfCount: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C2: int, _c1: bigint, _c2: bigint]

scala> 

scala> dfCount.show
+----+---+---+                                                                  
|  C2|_c1|_c2|
+----+---+---+
|2016|  4|  2|
|2017|  1|  1|
+----+---+---+
```